# How to add product reviews progmatically to add data on custom field

Tags: magento-1.9, import, review, programmatically

```
    $review = Mage::getModel('review/review')
->setEntityPkValue(intval($pressquote->product_id)) //product id
->setStatusId(intval($pressquote->status))
->setDetail($pressquote->text)
->setTitle('')
->setEntityId(1)                     
->setStatusId(intval($pressquote->status))          //approved
->setCustomerId(null)                       //null is for administrator
->setNickname($pressquote->source)
->setLink($pressquote->link)                            //custom field
->setLinktext($pressquote->linktext)                   //custom field
->setYear($pressquote->year)                            //custom field
->setStoreId(1)                                          
->setStores(array('base'))                              
->save();
```

I am not be able to save data on custom field above commented  for custom field.

Comment: have you added custom fileds in database table "review" or any other table?

Comment: if you are added in "review" table then but first clear cash and indexing in admin side after try again

Comment: I have cleared cash but did not get save even I update just after inserting but did not get desire result.

Comment: Which file or location added above code?

Comment: I have created a module and on crontroller xxxAction(), I am performing this task

Comment: Actuallay I am importing data from csv file and inserting it to database.

Comment: added custom fields in table "review" right?

Comment: yes Abdul added custom field.

Answer (score 0):

Based on comments, you want to import customers reviews from csv, so you can use this: https://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/product-review-import-export.html

This extension is not ready to multistore but works fine. You can edit Adapter (`MK_Reviewexport_Model_Convert_Adapter_Reviewimport`) and add your custom field.

```
class MK_Reviewexport_Model_Convert_Adapter_Reviewimport extends Mage_Catalog_Model_Convert_Adapter_Product
{
    public function saveRow(array $data)
    {
        $write = Mage::getSingleton ( 'core/resource' )->getConnection ( 'core_write' );
        $sku = $write->query ( 'select entity_id from `catalog_product_entity` where sku = "' . $data ['Sku'] . '" ' );
        $sku = $sku->fetch ();

        if ($sku) {
            $product_id = $sku ['entity_id'];
            if ($data ['customer_id'] == '') {
                $customerid = NULL;
            } else {
                $customerid = $data ['customer_id'];
            }
            $_review = Mage::getModel ( 'review/review' )
                ->setCreatedAt ( $data ['created_at'] )
                ->setEntityPkValue ( $product_id )->setEntityId ( 1 )
                ->setStatusId ( $data ['status_id'] )
                ->setTitle ( $data ['title'] )->setDetail ( $data ['detail'] )
                ->setStoreId ( 1 )
                ->setStores ( 1 )
                ->setCustomerId ( $customerid )
                // set your custom field here.
                ->setNickname ( $data ['nickname'] )->save ();

            if ($data ['option_id']) {
                $arr_data = explode ( "@", $data ['option_id'] );

                if (! empty ( $arr_data )) {

                    foreach ( $arr_data as $each_data ) {

                        $arr_rating = explode ( ":", $each_data );

                        if ($arr_rating [1] != 0) {

                            Mage::getModel ( 'rating/rating' )
                                ->setRatingId ( $arr_rating [0] )
                                ->setReviewId ( $_review->getId () )
                                ->setCustomerId ( $customerid )
                                ->addOptionVote ( $arr_rating [1], $product_id );
                        }
                    }
                }
                $_review->aggregate ();
            }
        }
    }
}
```